# How to display rows that when added together equal zero

Tags: sql

Been searching for a few weeks for a solution to this but have come up blank.

I have table of data similar to this:

```
client_ref  supplier_key  client_amount
1111        GBP           10
1111        GBP           -10
1111        EUR           50
2222        CHF           -22.5
2222        CHF           -20
3333        EUR           -27
3333        EUR           -52
3333        EUR            79
```

I need to extract all items where the client_ref and supplier_key match and the total of the client_amount equals zero. The output would look like this:

```
client_ref  supplier_key  client_amount
1111        GBP           10
1111        GBP           -10
3333        EUR           -27
3333        EUR           -52
3333        EUR            79
```

I have written the following that returns the totals but I need any help you could provide to change this to show the rows that make up the totals rather than just the overall results.

```
SELECT tbis.client_ref ,tbis.supplier_key ,sum(tbis.client_amount) 
FROM [XXXX].[dbo].[transaction] tbis 
WHERE tbis.tbis.client_amount !=0 
GROUP BY tbis.client_ref, tbis.supplier_key 
HAVING sum(tbis.client_amount) =0 
ORDER BY sum(tbis.client_amount)
```

Hope this makes sense and my first post is OK. Please feel free to critique my post.

Comment: Thank you for all for the answers that is great, they all seems to achieve the same results so I will have to do a little more work to understand each one and the approach that has been used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to use the SUM() windowing function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
( SELECT tbis.client_ref ,tbis.supplier_key,tbis.client_amount,
  SUM(tbis.client_amount) OVER (
    PARTITION BY tbis.client_ref, tbis.supplier_key) AS total_client_amount
  FROM [XXXX].[dbo].[transaction] tbis 
  WHERE tbis.client_amount !=0 
)
WHERE total_client_amount = 0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06e46/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM transactions AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    tbis.client_ref ,
    tbis.supplier_key,
    sum(tbis.client_amount) AS total
  FROM transactions tbis 
  WHERE tbis.client_amount !=0 
  GROUP BY tbis.client_ref, tbis.supplier_key 
  HAVING sum(tbis.client_amount) =0 
) AS t2  ON t1.client_ref = t2.client_ref
        AND t1.supplier_key = t2.supplier_key
ORDER BY t2.total;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95397/4)

Comment: This option worked well and also opened my eyes to being able to identify the contra items and then join back to the non contra items to be able to produce a very usefull report. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT client_ref ,supplier_key ,sum(client_amount) 
FROM   transaction
WHERE  client_amount <> 0 
GROUP BY client_ref, supplier_key 
HAVING sum(client_amount) = 0
```

Comment: This worked well and was a really simple approach. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think I can mark 2 posts as an answer can I? As I've just joined I don't have enough points to up vote :-( If I get some I'll come back and rectify. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tbis
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        client_ref, supplier_key
    FROM
        tbis
    GROUP by client_ref, supplier_key
    HAVING sum(client_amount) = 0
) match
ON match.client_ref = tbis.client_ref 
AND match.supplier_key = tbis.supplier_key
```

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3447/8/0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.* FROM Table1 AS t INNER JOIN
(SELECT [client_ref], [supplier_key], SUM([client_amount]) as Total
FROM Table1 GROUP BY [client_ref], [supplier_key]) AS sumTable
ON t.[client_ref] = sumTable.[client_ref] AND
t.[supplier_key] = sumTable.[supplier_key]
WHERE Total = 0;
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91f5b/12)**

Answer (score -1):

Make a new query for the data you want and join it by inner join to the query that produces the sums to restrict it to the lines you want.