# Restricting Returned Data In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I posted the question below and got some greate responses.

[How to display rows that when added together equal zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092492/how-to-display-rows-that-when-added-together-equal-zero)

The answer that came the closest to answering my problems was this:

```
    SELECT t1.*
FROM transactions AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    tbis.client_ref ,
    tbis.supplier_key,
    sum(tbis.client_amount) AS total
  FROM transactions tbis 
  WHERE tbis.client_amount !=0 
  GROUP BY tbis.client_ref, tbis.supplier_key 
  HAVING sum(tbis.client_amount) =0 
) AS t2  ON t1.client_ref = t2.client_ref
        AND t1.supplier_key = t2.supplier_key
ORDER BY t2.total;
```

The issue I'm having is that it is including rows in the result where the client amount = 0. I basicly need to carry out the below only on rows where the client amount is not 0.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this problem is occurring because either there is no primary key on your transactions table (as implied in your other post) or you are not joining on it. That means so long as there is at least 1 `client_ref` and `supplier_key` pair with a non-zero value, all values will be returned.
Either add a WHERE to the outer query

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM transactions AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    tbis.client_ref ,
    tbis.supplier_key,
    sum(tbis.client_amount) AS total
  FROM transactions tbis 
  WHERE tbis.client_amount !=0 
  GROUP BY tbis.client_ref, tbis.supplier_key 
  HAVING sum(tbis.client_amount) =0 
) AS t2  ON t1.client_ref = t2.client_ref
        AND t1.supplier_key = t2.supplier_key
WHERE t1.client_amount !=0 

ORDER BY t2.total;
```

Or also join on `client_amount`

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM transactions AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    tbis.client_ref ,
    tbis.supplier_key,
    sum(tbis.client_amount) AS total
  FROM transactions tbis 
  WHERE tbis.client_amount !=0 
  GROUP BY tbis.client_ref, tbis.supplier_key 
  HAVING sum(tbis.client_amount) =0 
) AS t2  ON t1.client_ref = t2.client_ref
        AND t1.supplier_key = t2.supplier_key
        AND t1.client_amount = t2.client_amount

ORDER BY t2.total;
```

Comment: Genius! Option 1 has sorted the problem a treat. You were spot on that I wasn't joining on the primary key as I had to get a total per customer. Thank you so much!