# Remove Rows That Sum Zero For A Given Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that will result in a customer bill being created on our SSRS 2008 R2 server. The SQL Server instance is also 2008 R2. The query is large and I don't want to post the entire thing for security reasons, etc.

What I need to do with the example data below, is to remove the two rows with 73.19 and -73.19 from the result set. So, if two rows have the same absolute value in the LineBalance column and their sum is 0 AND if they have the same value in the REF1 column, the should be removed from the result set. The line with REF1 = 14598 and a line balance of 281.47 should still be returned in the result set and the other two rows below with REF1 = 14598 should not be returned.

The point of this is to "hide" accounting errors and their correction from the customer. by "hide" I mean, not show it on the bill they get in the mail. What happened here is the customer was mistakenly billed 73.19 when they should have been billed 281.47. So, our AR dept. returned 73.19 to their account and charged them the correct amount of 281.47. As you can see they all have the same REF1 value.

[image: An Example Of My Data]

Comment: If you Sum LineBalance, and group by Ref1, the end number will be correct, because the positive and negative cancel each other out.

Comment: That is true. But I need the individual rows with the SysInvNum, not just the total balance. So in this case I need to make sure 3344298 would be returned as the value for SysInvNum. I'd be ok with grouping by REF1 as long as there is a way to do it and have the SysInvNum value be the correct one.

Comment: just out of curiosity, in this example, what would be the value of SysInvNum when you include all 3 rows?

Comment: Most AR/billing systems treat "credit memos" (the negative amount) similar to unapplied cash, in which case the -73.19 would get applied to the 73.19 LineBalance the same as if the customer had paid that amount, resulting in a $0 balance. Do you handle cash receipts and applications in this sytem? If so, you may be able to pull data from those cash application tables to show the tie between SysInvNum 3344296 and 3341758

Comment: How many errors are there? If there are only a few rows, you could just remove them seperately. If negative values exist in other valid rows in this table, it might me impossible to create desired effect safely.

Comment: @Jermey Right now all three rows appear on the customer bill. So they each have the value for their respective rows. The bill needs to only include the row with sysinvnum 3344298 though. The way I see to do it, is as I described in my question, I am just not sure what the SQL looks like to do that.

Comment: One way could be to group and order the transactions for each customer. When if negative transaction with the same absolute value appears after positive transaction, or vice versa, do not include them.

Comment: What would the expected outcome be if SysInvNum 3344298 was for 73.19 also instead of 281.47?

Comment: @chris544  This is what we call a credit/rebill and they happen regularly for various reasons. Wha tI'd like to do is get some help  writing the SQL that would remove the two offsetting amounts from the query I already have written. So, assume the example data above is a select * from ... and then I just need the where clause etc to eliminate the two rows I mentioned.

Comment: @BateTech - that is a very good question. What should happen then, is one of the two 73.19 amounts (positive amount) should appear in the result set, but not both. Either one would be fine, for the purpose of the customer bill.

Comment: OK, but if customer is charged 50.00 this month, gets rebill for -50.00, and pays 50 bucks again next month. Which of the 50.00 should be shown to him? How can we know it? And suddenly those 50.00 could appear in a completely different month/year.

Comment: If he gets charged 50 by mistake, pays it, then also gets a $50 credit, then he would have a $50 credit balance on his account.

Comment: Does the `PayAdjust` column represent customer payments?  If so, then it should be filled in for the 2 rows of 73.19

Comment: They could yes. But that is not likely, since we print customer bills 10 days after the end of the month, and there's a review process in place.  If it does happen then we have people to work that out with the customer. I just need help with my exact question. :D

Comment: PayAdjust is a customer receipt yes. It doesn't appear there because it wasn't a customer receipt. Our AR department made the correction without interaction from the customer.

Comment: I understand the need not to show complete data. can you confirm that there is no "applied to" (or similar) column somewhere that you can reference to offset value "a" against, If there is, but it is unpopulated, that could indicate a process problem rather than a system one. if it is populated then the problem goes away. If there isn't a column like that then @chris544 is correct, we need to know what criteria a human would use, to choose between multiple possible correct invoices, before we can automate it for you.

Comment: This question is similar, but he wants to include rows that equal zero. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092492/how-to-display-rows-that-when-added-together-equal-zero The sum.. over...partion by seems to be what I need, I just haven't been able to make it work

Comment: @G B Good points. There maybe another "flag" somewhere to indicate it is a credit/rebill. However, none of us have been able to find one to indicate a transaction as such. I also think there is more than one way our AR dept. processes these - which adds complexity. The rules a human would use right now are in my question. Two invoices, one positive, one negative, with the same REF1 value. They should cancel each other out and not be shown.

Comment: I updated the answer below. It's a mouthful, but finds the rows you need. I don't think you'll be able to do this in one clean query.

Comment: I will give that a whirl as soon as I can get VPN'd back into our network.

Comment: Applying the "human rules" to your data is easy enough but to refer to @chris544 example where there are two $50 and one -$50, which $50 amount should be returned. My life would be easier if I could tell SQL to "just pick one" :-) but unfortunately Jeremy's response (although clever) would eliminate all 3 records from your result set.

Comment: @GB, Check out my solution. It does just that - tells server to "pick (a random) one" using `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - yip, like it!

Comment: I appreciate everyone taking the time to give detailed answers. I am back at work this morning and about to try out each solution.

Comment: @BateTech Your comments caused me to dig a little deeper in our ERP system. I found that there are entries in our customer receipts table for each of the credit/rebills. I modified my query to first insert the resultset into a temp table. Then ran a second query to find all the credit rebills in the customer receipts and insert them into another temp table. Then a final third query to return the original result set without any of the sysinvnum that were in the second temp table and that did the trick. I'm not sure which response to mark as Answer.

Comment: @BrentLamborn I just updated my answer to add my comment from above about the other receipts table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most AR/billing systems treat "credit memos" (the negative amount) similar to cash, in which case the -73.19 would get applied to the 73.19 `LineBalance` the same as if the customer had paid that amount, resulting in a $0 balance.

**OPTION 1:**

Do you handle cash receipts and applications in this sytem? If so, you may be able to pull data from those cash application tables to show the tie between SysInvNum 3344296 and 3341758.

**OPTION 2:**

I'm assuming that `PayAdjust` column is used to reduce the balance after a customer has paid, and that LineBalance is a calculated column that is `Charges + PayAdjust`.

Most of the time when this occurs, the AR department would be responsible for applying the credit memo to an open invoice, so that the `PayAdjust` column would net $0 between the 2 rows, and this would cause the `LineBalance` to also be $0 on each of the 2 rows.  It may just be a training issue for the system that is being used.

This would cause the 3 rows in question to look like this, so you don't have an issue, you would just exclude the rows by adding `where LineBalance <> 0` to your query since the AR department (which applied the credit to begin with and so knows the answer to this question) explicitly stated which `LineBalance` the credit applies to:

**Option 2 Preferred data structure:**

```
SysInvNum   REF1        Charges               PayAdjust             LineBalance
----------- ----------- --------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
3344298     14598       281.47                0.00                  281.47
3344296     14598       -73.19                73.19                 0.00
3341758     14598       73.19                 -73.19                0.00
```

**OPTION 3:**

Without having this data from Option 1 or 2, you have make many assumptions and run the risk of inadvertently hiding the wrong rows.

That being said, here is a query that attempts to do what you are asking, but I would highly recommend checking with the AR dept to see if they can update "PayAdjust" for these records instead.

I added several test cases of scenarios that could cause issues, but this may not cover all the bases.

This query will only hide rows where one distinct matching negative value is found for a positive value, for the same REF1 and same DueDate.  It also makes sure that the original Charge invoice ID is prior to the credit since it can be assumed that a credit would not occur prior to the actual charge (Test case 6 shows both rows still because the credit has an SysInvNum that occurred before the charge).  If more than once match is found per `REF1, DueDate, and LineBalance`, then it will not hide the corresponding charge and credit lines (test cases 2 & 4).  Test case 3 sums in total to 0, but it still shows all 3 rows because the LineBalance values do not match exactly. These are all assumptions that I made to handle edge cases, so they can be adjusted as needed.

```
CREATE TABLE #SysInvTable (SysInvNum int not null primary key, REF1 int, Charges money, PayAdjust money, LineBalance as Charges + PayAdjust, DueDate date, REF2 int, Remark varchar(50), REM varchar(50));

INSERT INTO #SysInvTable(SysInvNum, REF1, Charges, PayAdjust, DueDate, Remark) 
VALUES
    --.....................................
    --Your test case
      (3344298, 14598, 281.47, 0, '2014-12-08','Your original test case. This one should stay.')
    , (3344296, 14598, -73.19, 0, '2014-12-08',null)
    , (3341758, 14598, 73.19, 0, '2014-12-08',null)
    --.....................................
    --Test case 2: How do you match these up? 
    , (2001, 2, 73.19, 0, '2015-01-06','Charge 2.1')
    , (2002, 2, 73.19, 0, '2015-01-06','Charge 2.2')
    , (2003, 2, 73.19, 0, '2015-01-06','Charge 2.3')
    , (2004, 2, -73.19, 0, '2015-01-06','Credit for charge 2.3')
    , (2005, 2, -73.19, 0, '2015-01-06','Credit for charge 2.1') 
    --.....................................
    --Test case 3
    , (3001, 3, 73.19, 0, '2015-01-06','Charge 3.1')
    , (3002, 3, 73.19, 0, '2015-01-06','Charge 3.2')
    , (3003, 3, -146.38, 0, '2015-01-06','Credit for charges 3.1 and 3.2') 
    --.....................................
    --Test case 4: Do you hide 4001 or 4002? 
    , (4001, 4, 73.19, 0, '2015-01-06','Cable')
    , (4002, 4, 73.19, 0, '2015-01-06','Internet')
    , (4003, 4, -73.19, 0, '2015-01-06','Misc Credit')
    --.....................................
    --Test case 5: remove all lines except the first
    , (5000, 5, 9.99, 0, '2015-01-06','Charge 5.0 (Should stay)')
    , (5001, 5, 11.11, 0, '2015-01-06','Charge 5.1')
    , (5002, 5, 22.22, 0, '2015-01-06','Charge 5.2')
    , (5003, 5, 33.33, 0, '2015-01-06','Charge 5.3')
    , (5004, 5, -11.11, 0, '2015-01-06','Credit for charge 5.1')
    , (5005, 5, -33.33, 0, '2015-01-06','Credit for charge 5.3') 
    , (5006, 5, -22.22, 0, '2015-01-06','Credit for charge 5.2') 
    --.....................................
    --Test case 6: credit occurs before charge, so keep both
    , (6000, 6, -73.19, 0, '2015-01-06','Credit occurs before charge')
    , (6001, 6, 73.19, 0, '2015-01-06','Charge 6.1')
;

SELECT i.* 
FROM #SysInvTable i
WHERE i.SysInvNum not in 
(
    SELECT IngoreInvNum = case when c.N = 1 then max(t.SysInvNum) else min(t2.SysInvNum) end
    FROM #SysInvTable t
    INNER JOIN #SysInvTable t2 
        ON t.ref1 = t2.ref1 
        AND t.DueDate = t2.DueDate
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 2 as N) AS c --used to both both T and T2 SysInvNum's to exclude
    WHERE 1=1
        AND t.LineBalance > 0 AND t2.LineBalance < 0
        AND t.SysInvNum < t2.SysInvNum --make sure the credit came in after the positive SysInvNum 
        AND t.LineBalance = t2.LineBalance * -1
    GROUP BY t.REF1, t.DueDate, abs(t.LineBalance), c.n
    HAVING Count(*) = 1
)
;

DROP TABLE #SysInvTable;
```

Comment: I like this. It is basically similar to SQL Server 2012 solution (looks at consequent transactions, credit first and happens after each other (or the same day)). But someone has to keep updating that PayAdjust. Maybe on solution would be to create a trigger (yes a deadly trigger) that automatically adjusts Payadjust column. Updates would happen automatically fast and would be mostly accurate. Some special cases could be handled manually after that.

Comment: @chris544 The query in this solution doesn't rely on PayAdjust, but my point there is that the data in the system should already be structured this way, or should at least have another table that ties the charge and credit together (this would be the same table that tracks customer payments), so this query that is trying to infer which charge this credit is for likely is not needed bc either a)  it is a process issue where the AR department should be applying the credit directly to a charge if that is what the credit is for or b)  the data to tie them together is in another table.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with your points. The question was about weather it should always be the responsibility of AR department to add those PayAdjusts or that could be done in a smart way automatically to even more reduce the number of actions that have to be done manually.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I would imagine that the system already has functionality to reverse a charge with a process that is likely easier to entering a manual adjustment, but AR dept (or support person handling customer complaint calls) just may not be aware of this functionality. Most systems have this ability built in. If not, it gets tricky adding triggers or updating the tables directly bc the application business logic may expect certain data structures (and you might miss updating other related tables that the application logic would update that you don't know about).

Answer (score 7):

I would add a field that would contain explicit flag telling you that a certain charge was a mistake/reversal of a mistake and then it is trivial to filter out such rows. Doing it on the fly could make your reports rather slow.

But, to solve the given problem as is we can do like this. The solution assumes that `SysInvNum` is unique.

### Create a table with sample data

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (SysInvNum int, REF1 int, LineBalance money);

INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (3344299, 14602, 558.83);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (3344298, 14598, 281.47);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (3344297, 14602, -95.98);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (3344296, 14598, -73.19);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (3341758, 14598, 73.19);

INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (11, 100, 50.00);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (12, 100, -50.00);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (13, 100, 50.00);

INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (21, 200, -50.00);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (22, 200, -50.00);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (23, 200, 50.00);

INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (31, 300, -50.00);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (32, 300, 50.00);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (33, 300, -50.00);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (34, 300, 50.00);

INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (41, 400, 50.00);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (42, 400, -50.00);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (43, 400, 50.00);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (44, 400, -50.00);
INSERT INTO @T (SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance) VALUES (45, 400, 50.00);
```

I've added few more cases that have multiple mistakes.

### Number and count rows

```
SELECT
    SysInvNum
    , REF1
    , LineBalance
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY REF1, LineBalance ORDER BY SysInvNum) AS rn
    , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY REF1, ABS(LineBalance)) AS cc1
FROM @T AS TT
```

This is the result set:

```
SysInvNum    REF1    LineBalance    rn    cc1
11           100      50.00         1     3
12           100     -50.00         1     3
13           100      50.00         2     3
21           200     -50.00         1     3
23           200      50.00         1     3
22           200     -50.00         2     3
31           300     -50.00         1     4
32           300      50.00         1     4
33           300     -50.00         2     4
34           300      50.00         2     4
41           400      50.00         1     5
42           400     -50.00         1     5
43           400      50.00         2     5
44           400     -50.00         2     5
45           400      50.00         3     5
3341758      14598    73.19         1     2
3344296      14598   -73.19         1     2
3344298      14598   281.47         1     1
3344297      14602   -95.98         1     1
3344299      14602   558.83         1     1
```

You can see that those rows that have mistakes have count > 1. Also, pairs of mistakes have same row numbers. So, we need to remove/hide those rows that have count > 1 and those that have two same row numbers.

### Determine rows to remove

```
WITH
CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        SysInvNum
        , REF1
        , LineBalance
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY REF1, LineBalance ORDER BY SysInvNum) AS rn
        , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY REF1, ABS(LineBalance)) AS cc1
    FROM @T AS TT
)
, CTE_ToRemove
AS
(
    SELECT
        SysInvNum
        , REF1
        , LineBalance
        , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY REF1, rn) AS cc2
    FROM CTE_rn
    WHERE CTE_rn.cc1 > 1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_ToRemove
WHERE CTE_ToRemove.cc2 = 2
```

This is another intermediate result:

```
SysInvNum    REF1    LineBalance    cc2
12           100     -50.00         2
11           100      50.00         2
21           200     -50.00         2
23           200      50.00         2
32           300      50.00         2
31           300     -50.00         2
33           300     -50.00         2
34           300      50.00         2
42           400     -50.00         2
41           400      50.00         2
43           400      50.00         2
44           400     -50.00         2
3344296      14598   -73.19         2
3341758      14598    73.19         2
```

Now, we just put all this together.

### Final query

```
WITH
CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        SysInvNum
        , REF1
        , LineBalance
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY REF1, LineBalance ORDER BY SysInvNum) AS rn
        , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY REF1, ABS(LineBalance)) AS cc1
    FROM @T AS TT
)
, CTE_ToRemove
AS
(
    SELECT
        SysInvNum
        , REF1
        , LineBalance
        , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY REF1, rn) AS cc2
    FROM CTE_rn
    WHERE CTE_rn.cc1 > 1
)
SELECT *
FROM @T AS TT
WHERE
    TT.SysInvNum NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT CTE_ToRemove.SysInvNum
        FROM CTE_ToRemove
        WHERE CTE_ToRemove.cc2 = 2
    )
ORDER BY SysInvNum;
```

Result:

```
SysInvNum    REF1    LineBalance
13           100       50.00
22           200      -50.00
45           400       50.00
3344297      14602    -95.98
3344298      14598    281.47
3344299      14602    558.83
```

Note, that final result doesn't have any rows with REF = 300, because there were two corrected mistakes, that balanced each other completely.

Comment: This is one hell of a query. Not sure if understood it entirely. Too much SQL on this page already :) SQL Server's 2012 LAG(), LEAD() makes this a piece of cake and gives control over removing consequent bad looking transactions in so few lines though.

Comment: @chris544 I think the main "trick" here is using `ABS(LineBalance)`, which allows to group transactions that have the same amounts with different signs together. The result doesn't depend on the order of these transactions. `LAG` and `LEAD` take the order of transactions into account. These are just different solutions that strictly speaking produce different results.

Comment: Yeah, that is all right, but it seems that there should some more intuitive solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

It's clunky, but this allows you to identify the matching negative offenders. You'll need to exclude the sysInvNum in both columns from your resultset

```
Create table #tmp( SysInvNum int,Ref1 int, LineBalance decimal(8,2))

insert into #tmp
values(3344299,14602,558.83)
,(3344298,14598,281.47)
,(3344297,14602,-95.98)
,(3344296,14598,-73.19)
,(3341758,14598,73.19)

--Select * From #tmp

Select * 
INTO #t1
From #tmp
 Where LineBalance < 0

--Select * From #t1

Select SysInvNum1 = #tmp.SysInvNum, SysInvNum2 = #T1.SysInvNum 
INTO #T2
From #tmp 
LEFT JOIN #t1 On #tmp.Ref1 = #T1.Ref1 and #tmp.LineBalance = -#T1.LineBalance
where #t1.SysInvNum is not null


Select * From 
#tmp
Where SysInvNum not in(
Select SysInvNum1 from #t2
union Select SysInvNum2 from #t2
)

drop table #tmp
drop table #t1
drop table #t2
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for **SQL Server 2012 only**, but decided to leave it here if someone has to do something similar in the future because it is pretty straight forward.

....

This should only remove two transactions for specific recepient if their sum is 0 and there are no other transactions between them (and the negative transaction happens after positive transaction). It is more conservative and safe.

There should be information about the order of transactions. Something like date column. Than you should order by this column instead of PRIMARY KEY column in PARTITION BY statement.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Receipts', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Receipts

CREATE TABLE Receipts
(
    SysInvNum INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    REF1 INT, 
    LineBalance DECIMAL(10,2)
)


INSERT INTO Receipts
values
    (14602,558.83),
    (14598,281.47),
    (14602,-95.98),
    (14598,73.19),
    (14598,-73.19),
    (14598,73.19),
    (14598,73.19),
    (14598, 215.6),
    (14598,73.19)


WITH ghosts AS
(
    SELECT SysInvNum, REF1, LineBalance, 
        LAG(LineBalance, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY REF1 ORDER BY SysInvNum) PreviousLineBalance,
        LEAD(LineBalance, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY REF1 ORDER BY SysInvNum) NextLineBalance
    FROM Receipts
)
SELECT r.SysInvNum, r.REF1, r.LineBalance
FROM Receipts r
JOIN ghosts g On (r.SysInvNum = g.SysInvNum)
WHERE NOT (g.LineBalance + g.PreviousLineBalance = 0 AND g.LineBalance < 0)
    AND NOT (g.LineBalance + g.NextLineBalance = 0 AND g.LineBalance > 0)
ORDER BY r.SysInvNum
```

Comment: Yeah, that query was too short to be true. If you have to write your own LAG and LEAD, this solution is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Check out what I came with. It uses just `ROW_NUMBER` and `COUNT` and doesn't rely on the order of transactions.