# SQL: Remove Rows That Sum Zero For A Given Key (Additional Q.)

Tags: sql-server

Found this question had already been answered about a year ago, but I am looking to 'build' further on the issue.  The original response appears to sum zero in a direct 1:1 situation.  If there is a debit in the amount of xyz for customer A and a corresponding credit in the exact same amount of -xyz for customer A, delete the two transactions.  I am looking to delete any combinations of multiple amounts that sum to zero, as well as the 1:1 matches.

Assume that Customer A has transactions of 1.50, 2.50, 3.50, -2.00, -7.25, -4.00.  I would like to delete the transactions of [2.50, 3.50, -2.00, -4.00] and retain the following transactions: [1.50, -7.25]

[image: Raw Invoices]

[image: Filtered Invoices Result Set]

Thanks in advance!
sven

Anticipated Results:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table.tableizer-table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    } 
    .tableizer-table td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    .tableizer-table th {
        background-color: #104E8B; 
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>SysInvNum</th><th>Customer</th><th>Charges</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>11</td><td>100</td><td>1.50</td></tr>
 <tr><td>15</td><td>100</td><td>-7.25</td></tr>
 <tr><td>20</td><td>200</td><td>35.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>24</td><td>300</td><td>10.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>26</td><td>300</td><td>18.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>30</td><td>400</td><td>300.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>31</td><td>400</td><td>175.00</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Original Data

```
<style type="text/css">
    table.tableizer-table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    } 
    .tableizer-table td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    .tableizer-table th {
        background-color: #104E8B; 
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>SysInvNum</th><th>Customer</th><th>Charges</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>11</td><td>100</td><td>1.50</td></tr>
 <tr><td>12</td><td>100</td><td>2.50</td></tr>
 <tr><td>13</td><td>100</td><td>3.50</td></tr>
 <tr><td>14</td><td>100</td><td>-2.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>15</td><td>100</td><td>-7.25</td></tr>
 <tr><td>16</td><td>100</td><td>-4.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>17</td><td>200</td><td>30.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>18</td><td>200</td><td>40.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>19</td><td>200</td><td>-70.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>20</td><td>200</td><td>35.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>21</td><td>300</td><td>15.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>22</td><td>300</td><td>25.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>23</td><td>300</td><td>-30.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>24</td><td>300</td><td>10.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>25</td><td>300</td><td>-10.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>26</td><td>300</td><td>18.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>27</td><td>400</td><td>-50.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>28</td><td>400</td><td>-100.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>29</td><td>400</td><td>-50.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>30</td><td>400</td><td>300.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>31</td><td>400</td><td>175.00</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Initial question and answers:
[Remove Rows That Sum Zero For A Given Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829960/remove-rows-that-sum-zero-for-a-given-key)

Comment: Please put the data as text, we cant copy/paste from pictures.

Comment: Sys   InvNum Customer Charges
11 100 1.50
12 100 2.50
13 100 3.50
14 100 -2.00
15 100 -7.25
16 100 -4.00
17 200 30.00
18 200 40.00
19 200 -70.00
20 200 35.00
21 300 15.00
22 300 25.00
23 300 -30.00
24 300 10.00
25 300 -10.00
26 300 18.00
27 400 -50.00
28 400 -100.00
29 400 -50.00
30 400 300.00
31 400 175.00

Comment: dont post comment just edit your question

Comment: You haven't asked a question. As a first advice: you need an algorithm. Most simple thing that comes to mind: add all n values. Sum = 0? Then done. Else try all n-1 combinations and so on. A recursive function that stops at the first encounter of sum = 0. Nothing I would try with SQL actually. Use a programming language for that. There may be many more algorithms or optimizations to mine. So your first task is to settle for one algorithm. I doubt you'll find one where SQL turns out to be an appropriate tool.